# Android | Теряется анимация при сворачивании приложения

Tags: java, android

У меня есть простая анимация открытия активити с поиском, делается это следующим образом:

```
        Intent searchActivity = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                Pair.create(searchEditText, "searchTransition"));
        startActivity(searchActivity, options.toBundle());
```

Но при сворачивании и повторном открытии приложения анимация теряется, и активити с поиском закрывается со стандартной анимацией. Оно так и должно работать, или следует каким-то образом снова устанавливать связь между активити?
[Видео анимации](https://vimple.co/9590a2fc8f77454d8632c1ef81ebb13a)

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/file_wiki_search_form"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/search"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="12dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:textColor="?attr/mainTextColor"
                    android:textColorHint="?attr/secondTextColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:transitionName="searchTransition"
                    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_search_outline_28dp" />
```

Comment: Что такое searchEditText? Покажите его кусок кода

Comment: @ArtyMorris добавил